# VueJS 2.0: Using V-if to Check the Existence of a Custom Prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have created a custom modal component using VueJS 2.0 with a prop of 'close'.  I basically have it working like I want, but would like to improve it a bit.

One feature I have is the option to add a close button as follows:

**Add a custom prop of close="true" in the HTML**

```
<modal close="true">
Etc...
</modal>
```

**Use a V-IF conditional statement in the JS file**

```
<button v-if="close == 'true'></button>
```

The result is that if the property of close is set to true then the close button appears, if not it does not.  This is what I want and it works.

My question is can I simplify this solution so that I can simply set the html as follows:  `<modal close>...</modal>`.

Then I would simply check if the property of close exists.  I tried to do so using `<button v-if="close"></button>`, but that did not work.

So, what I'd like to know is if this is possible and (if so) how to do it.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set the default of the property to be `false`, then you can check whether the property is exactly `false` to determine whether or not to show the button:

```
props: {
  close: {
    default: false,
  },
}
```

Then you can check like this:

```
<button v-if="close !== false"></button>
```

When you add the `close` property to the `modal` component without specifying a value, the value will equal an empty string: `''`. So, it won't be equal to false, and will thus display the close button.

Comment: @Moshe Were you using the strict equal operator? An empty string in javascript is falsey, so `'' == false` is true, but if you do `'' === false` it will return false. Same with `!=` and `!==`. thanksd's solution is working fine for me.

Comment: @Snuffleupagus This is what I used:  `<modal close>`  |  `<button v-if="close !== false"></button>` |  `props: {
  close: { default: false }
 }`.  I also tried `<modal close="adfad">`, which did not work.  Only `<modal close="true">` worked.

Comment: @Moshe Are you using an up to date version of vue? Could you maybe post the full code via a fiddle or something? I have a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/22864/).

Comment: @Snuffleupagus I must have had some typo.  I copy and pasted your code into my file and it worked.  But now I have a different issue - this works for ANY VALUE for close.  For instance, `close="adsflkjadf"` works.  As does `close="false"`.  Is there a solution that will work ONLY for close (without any set property)?  Either way, thanks for your help.

Comment: `v-if="close=''"`